# Laravel search; filter by a foreign table then again filter results with the local table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables 'stocks' and 'products'. They have one to many relationship.

Model -
Product.php

```
public function stocks(){
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\Stock\Entities\Stock');
}
```

Model - Stock.php

```
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Product\Entities\Product')->withTrashed();
}
```

while searching for stocks, i want to search by the product name as well. I have a search created for searching keywords and an optional checkbox for low stocks. So if i want to search for a low stocked product, for eg say 'Shoes', it should show me shoes whose quantities are low.

This works perfectly as long as the search type is among the stock table's columns. But when i want to search records based on product name(in product table), then filter these resultant records based on low stocks(in stock table). there are no results displayed.

```
class ProductName implements Filter
{
   public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value, $checkbox)
   {
      if($checkbox == null) {
         $a = $builder->whereHas ('product', function ($query) use ($value) 
         {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%'); //this works fine.
         });
      } else {
        $a = $builder->whereHas ('product', function ($query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
        })->whereRaw('quantity < low_stock_threshold'); //This is meant for two search filters;one for searching in product table then filtering the results againtst stock table according to low quantity.
      }
      return $a;
   }
}
```

the commented line is which doesnot work. Please help if someone can fix this.

Comment: Can you show SQL query? `echo $a->toSql(); die;`

Comment: select * from `stocks` where exists (select * from `products` where `stocks`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `name` LIKE ?) and quantity < low_stock_threshold and `stocks`.`deleted_at` is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw my sql query and edited as needed and it worked. Thanks @Egretos for the suggestion.

```
class ProductName implements Filter
{
   public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value, $checkbox)
   {
       if($checkbox == null) {
           $a = $builder->whereHas ('product', function ($query) use ($value) {
               $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
           });
       } else {
           $a = $builder->whereHas ('product', function ($query) use ($value) {
               $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
           })->whereRaw('`stocks`.`quantity` < `stocks`.`low_stock_threshold`'); //edited this line and it worked.

       }
       return $a;
   }

}
```